# How do I use ACLs on an encfs filesystem?

Tags: debian, file-permissions, disk-encryption

I have a Debian server which I've set up file ACLs on. However, ACLs on the `encfs` filesystem I've made don't seem to be handled properly. The mount directory is setguid and has a `default:group::rwx` ACL entry, but files and directories I make in the root are set to be non-group-writable. I've also tried making a directory on the filesystem and manually setting the default ACL on it, but files and directories I make in that directory don't have group write permission either.

I think I'm missing a mount option or something (I had to change `/etc/fstab` to add an `acl` option for the root filesystem when I set up ACLs), but I get a `fuse: unknown option` error from trying to mount with `acl` or `extended_security`.

The exact command I'm using to mount the filesystem is `encfs -o allow_other /home/blackl/.this /home/blackl/this`.

How do I get the encrypted filesystem to handle ACLs properly?

Comment: AFAIK from a quick Google search Fuse, and anything based on it doesn't support ACLs.  If you need ACLs, you probably need to look at DM-Crypt, Truecrypt, or something else.

Comment: Okay…how do I encrypt a directory using `dm-crypt`?